# Libcurl Download Picture with URL

Tags: url, path, libcurl

I'm trying to download pictures from my webserver and save them in an folder.

```
<CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;
CURLcode res;
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX];
std::string soutfilename = "C:\\Users\\MDrazyk\\counTechTemp\\";
string lawl= getURL(einstellung[8][0]);
const char *url = lawl.c_str();
curl = curl_easy_init();

for(int g = 0; g < std::stoi(einstellung[0][7]); ++g){
    string str = einstellung[8][0];
    soutfilename =soutfilename +str;
    strcpy(outfilename,soutfilename.c_str());
if (curl) {
    fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

}
}
 curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
```

and getURL:

```
std::string getURL(std::string a) {
 std::string url = "http://192.168.240.1/files/";
 url = url + a;
retur url;
```

}

einstellung[8][0] = name of the picture

When I start the program it saves the pictures in the folder they are empty.
When I add the Url Manually then the first picture is complete and sometimes the next one is broken.

Comment: The key is probably in exactly what the HTTP server responds. Switch on CURLOPT_VERBOSE and investigate the details!

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string soutfilename = "C:\\Users\\MDrazyk\\counTechTemp\\";

for(int g = 0; g < std::stoi(einstellung[0][7]); ++g){
    soutfilename = soutfilename + str;
}
```

You're appending to `soutfilename` over and over. You're ending up with a path like "C:\Users\MDrazyk\counTechTemp\fileone.jpgfiletwo.jpgfilethree.jpg"

---

```
for(int g = 0; g < std::stoi(einstellung[0][7]); ++g){
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
    }
}

fclose(fp);
```

You're opening the file inside the for loop, but only closing it at the very end. You'll end up with a bunch of files that aren't closed properly. Call `fclose` at the same scope where you call `fopen`.

---

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
```

If your intent is to write to a `FILE*`, you don't need to set [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html). The default value of [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) is [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/), so simply setting [CURLOPT_WRITEDATA](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html) to the `FILE*` is sufficient.

If that doesn't solve your problem, you'll need to show us the contents of your `write_data` method.